# iota increment vector of a class c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, overloading, increment

I recently have been taking advantage of the `<numeric>` `iota` statement for incrementing a vector of type `int`. But now I am trying to use the statement for incrementing an explicit class with 2 members.

So here is the usage with a vector of integers:

```
vector<int> n(6);
iota(n.begin(), n.end(), 1);
```

Given that `Obj` class has an integer member called `m`. The constructor initializes `m` to its corresponding integer argument. Here is what I am trying to do now:

```
vector<Obj> o(6);
iota(o.begin(), o.end(), {m(1)});
```

I've attempted making a class increment overload somewhat like this:

```
Obj& operator ++() {
    *this.m++;
    return *this;
}
```

But I think either my constructor is not designed for this overload or vice versa. How can I modify my constructor and overload to increment an object member with iota? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your description: `iota` increments the value you pass it (the third argument), not the elements of the range it modifies/traverses. Do you want to modify those elements by incrementing them, or overwrite them with the incrementing value?

Comment: @dyp I want to overwrite them with the incrementing value since my constructor already made them the value of 0. Is that possible?

Comment: `iota(o.begin(), o.end(), Obj(1));`

Comment: @KerrekSB Kerrek,thanks I will try that. Do I still need my increment overload for that?

Comment: Yes, you need the overload since iota will call it (how else will it "increment" the object?).

Comment: Well you could also *generate* them with increasing values ;) With an appropriate iterator, `vector<int> n(make_iota_iterator(6, Obj(1)), iota_iterator<Obj>());` or something like that (with a custom `make_iota_iterator` function).

Comment: @KerrekSB okay thanks, I'm sure I've already tried that but maybe there was a syntax error somewhere. Does that overload look right?

Comment: As a side remark, I would recommend against providing an `operator++` just to make your type compatible with `iota`. Rather, I'd try to define some generation function (stateful, a closure/lambda) that is called N times and returns an incremented value each time (not using `operator++` but some custom function or a conversion from `int`).

Comment: A simple, but not optimal solution could be: `vector<Obj> o(6); int i; generate(o.begin(), o.end(), [&i]{ return Obj(i++); });`. This does not require implicit conversion, but it still needlessly creates 6 objects just to overwrite them in the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question. Does the following code match what you want?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Object {
 public:
  Object(int value = 0)
      : m_value(value) { }
  Object& operator++() {
    m_value++;
    return *this;
  }
  int value() const {
    return m_value;
  }
 private:
  int m_value;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Object> os(10);
  std::iota(os.begin(), os.end(), 0);
  for(const auto & o : os) {
    std::cout << o.value() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Compiled with gcc 4.8 on OS X 10.7.4 I get:

```
$ g++ iota-custom.cpp -std=c++11
$ ./a.out 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: thanks, I gave you the accepted answer because of the lengthy explaination. Brett's looks good too. Thanks to everyone though!

Comment: This will work fine without Object::operator++ (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6248417793fec446). It works because the constructor is not marked as `explicit`.

Answer (score 2):

*Updated: I changed the answer to provide the functionality requested in the comments: namely, to be able to update multiple fields.*

Format your class in a manner similar to the following. You will need to overload the `++` operator to increment both `_m` and `_c`.

```
class Obj {
    private:
        int _m;
        char _c;

    public:
        Obj(int m, char c) : _m(m), _c(c)
        {
        }

        MyClass operator++()
        {
            _m++;
            _n++;

            return *this;
        }
};
```

The following code will initialize the vector `o` with 6 `Obj`'s, each containing ascending values for `_m` and `_c` starting from 1.

```
vector<Obj> o(6);
iota(o.begin(), o.end(), Obj(1, 1));
```

Comment: @Brett_Wolfington thanks, does this work without a `++` overload?

Comment: Yes it does. No ++ overload is required.

Comment: will this also work by incrementing 2 members simultaneously; given a second member, say of type `char`?

Comment: @Jim22150 At this point, I'd suggest asking a new question that contains your issue in more detail. Best would be a complete (compilable) example that contains everything but the expression to create/modify the elements of the vector.

Comment: Jim - I updated the code to answer your question. The new code will indeed increment 2 members simultaneously, but *will* require overloading `++`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <numeric>      // std::iota
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Obj
{
private:
    int m_;
public:
    auto value() const -> int { return m_; }
    Obj( int m = 0 ): m_( m ) {}
};

auto main() -> int
{
    vector<Obj> v(6);
    iota( v.begin(), v.end(), 1 );
}
```

Comment: this might be my favorite answer; I'm loving v.11's type auto. I already have accepted an answer though. I will play around with this!