# STL iota include file change

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c-preprocessor, iota

The `iota` function was formerly in the `<algorithm>` header. It has been change to `<numeric>`.

I need to keep the old way for backward compatibility so I would like to use preprocessor option to select the right header to include.

When does this changed and which preprocessor option should I use?

Comment: Maybe relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242524/converting-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: You [test for C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support) and depending on the result you pick which header to use.

Comment: @TonyJ: That's about `itoa`, not [std::iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Comment: @NathanOliver yes! something like ````#if __cplusplus <= 199711L```` would be nice. But starting from which version of c++ does it use numeric?

Comment: @jvtrudel per [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), C++11

Comment: @jvtrudel: compare against `201103L`. Or you could just include both if it doesn't impact your compile time unacceptably.

Comment: I know where to find the documentation, but I'm not familiar with the versioning scheme. It don't appear in the documentation as far as I can see @NathanOliver

Comment: @jvtrudel Not sure if there is a versioning scheme defined somewhere.  You can find the values though in [cpp.predefined] in the standard. (most likely there are using YYYYMM)

Comment: @FredLarson Oh I just learned something, I read what std::iota does, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota, but what what does iota stand for?

Comment: @TonyJ as I stated in my answer, iota is the Greek letter ι and the name iota is taken from the programming language APL. It's a Greek letter used in mathematics to denote a set of consecutive numbers.

Comment: `iota` and `itoa` do look dangerously similar.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `iota` has been in `<numeric>` going [all the way back to the SGI STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iota.html). When was it in `<algorithm>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iota](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/iota/) (from the Greek ι) was re-introduced in `<numeric>` when [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) arrived, as you can see in the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/). So you check if your in an environment without it, and include the old header, or else, include the new header.

Something like this might do the trick:

```
#if __cplusplus <= 199711L
  #include <algorithm>
#else
  #include <numeric>
#endif
```

[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) sets the value of `__cplusplus` to `201103L`. That asserts full conformance to the 2011 standard; it doesn't tell you about partial conformance or compiler extensions. If `__cplusplus` is set to 201103L, then either the compiler fully conforms or it's lying to you. If it's not, then you can't really tell which features it supports.

Read more in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support).

Moreover, this Quora [post](https://www.quora.com/What-new-algorithms-were-introduced-in-the-C++-standard-library-in-C++11) also agrees with the change (or to be honest; re-introduce) of `std::iota` to have happened with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

---

<sub>If you can afford it, just include both libraries.</sub>

Comment: I don't need a proof... Just want to understand how to dig in the STL source code and history. Looking at the header source is a good hint, but where is the git/svn of STL?

Comment: I don't know @jvtrudel, when I had found myself in similar situations digging into the header or/and source files was the way to go! =)

Comment: Do you have any evidence that `iota` has ever been in `<algorithm>`?

Comment: Apart from the Quora link @T.C., which mentions its existence, but not its header file, it is evident from this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579703/iota-increment-vector-of-a-class-c) that at least two humans used from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: So basically you claim it was "moved in C++11" because of an internal GCC implementation detail (that `<algorithm>` by happenstance pulls in `<random>` which by happenstance pulls in `<numeric>`)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @T.C., but I would say it was re-introduced, rather than moved...Updated my answer.

Comment: I have a collaborator that use it from algorithm; that's why i need preproc option. At least, that's what I guess, but he have a whole bunch of other headers... but not numeric.

Answer (score 4):

`iota` was never "moved" from `<algorithm>`. C++03 doesn't have `std::iota` in any header, and no conforming implementation can provide it, because `iota` is not a reserved name and this is required to work:

```
#define iota arbitrary preprocessing token sequence like this and *that and "!" and \
             -13833rfa231fn7or.other.line.noise.that.happens.to.be.a.pp.number
#include <every-standard-header-here>
```

It was added to `<numeric>` in C++11 and was in [the SGI STL](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iota.html)'s `<numeric>` too as an extension. It has never been in `<algorithm>` and so can't possibly be moved from it.

Now, because standard library headers are allowed to include each other in arbitrary ways, it happens that GCC <= 5's `<algorithm>` in C++11 mode included `<random>` by happenstance, which included `<numeric>` by happenstance. That's a mere implementation detail that you shouldn't be relying upon, and GCC 6 no longer does that. The fix for that is to simply include the correct header, which is, and has always been, `<numeric>`.

Comment: Interesting... But the compiler that I have seen use ````std::iota```` without ````<numeric>```` is a mvsc, not gcc. But I do not know the version, that's why I was looking at a change in the STL library. The same (or even worst) mess probably happened their.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is check if the `__cplusplus` variable is below a certain point and if it is `#include <algorithm>` if not then `#include <numeric>`

```
#if __cplusplus <= 199711L
  #include <algorithm>
#else
  #include <numeric>
#endif
```

This should work for just about any library that you need to do this with, just note that you may have to change the `199711L` to the appropriate number.